# C program, printf char* crashes

Tags: c, string

I have a structure which is composed of a `char*` and many attributes.

I can't print my `char*` as a *string*, it just crashes.

Here is my code :

```
int main() {
    sommet_t* sommet = creerSommet("rouge", 5, NULL);
    printf("Couleur : %s", sommet->couleur);
    return 0;
}
```

And my sommet.c :

```
sommet_t* creerSommet(char* couleur, int distance, sommet_t* pere) {
    sommet_t* sommet =  malloc(sizeof(sommet_t));
    sommet->distance = distance;
    sommet->couleur = (char*)malloc((strlen(couleur)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(sommet->couleur,couleur);
    sommet->pere = pere;
}
```

I absolutely don't know what's wrong in it.

Edit : sommet.h

```
#ifndef __SOMMET_H__
#define __SOMMET_H__

typedef struct sommet_type {
    char *couleur;
    int distance;
    struct sommet_type *pere;
} sommet_t;

sommet_t* creerSommet(char*, int, sommet_t*);

#endif
```

Comment: Added in the post

Comment: `sizeof(char)` in `(char*)malloc((strlen(couleur)+1) * sizeof(char));` is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: ___Please don't change code in question in a way which makes the answers invalid.___

Answer (score 3):

You should return the object from the function `creerSommet`

```
sommet_t* creerSommet(char* couleur, int distance, sommet_t* pere) {
    sommet_t* sommet =  malloc(sizeof(sommet_t));
    sommet->distance = distance;
    sommet->couleur = (char*)malloc((strlen(couleur)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(sommet->couleur,couleur);
    sommet->pere = pere;
    return sommet;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it but it still crashes

Comment: sommet->couleur = (char*)malloc((strlen(couleur)+1) * sizeof(char)); Isn't this only ever allocating space for one character since coleur is uninitialized at this stage, or worse, maybe some length of garbage data?

Comment: @synchronizer couleur is my parameter which is "rouge"

Comment: @synchronizer that's the function parameter.

Comment: If I try to display "distance", it displays 0 instead of 5 but it is not crashing. :(

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return `sommet` from the function.

FWIW, any function, which is expected to return some value, if does not `return` a value, and the return value is used in caller, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.1, *Function definitions*

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

That said,

- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)
- Always check for success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` in C. Using it as a multiplier is redundant.

Comment: Oh that's it, I got no error in IDE or compiler, got to pay more attention with this language :(

Comment: It still crashing tho :x

Comment: enable warnings... or use a proper compiler. This problem is trivial to catch.

Comment: Using codeblocks with GNU GCC Compiler, can you give me any good one please ?

Comment: @XnateMaxime: enable warnings.